# Approach to building an image scaling tool using Pixi.js 3.x

Tags: pixi.js

I'm building an authoring tools which needs to allow users to input images and later position and scale those images. What's the best way to implement image/sprite scaling using Pixi.js 3.x?

[image: Example scale]

Comment: http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=basics&f=click.js&title=Click

Comment: The pixi example referenced above demonstrates scaling, which is simple enough, but doesn't address how to best implement a user stretchable image using anchor points as shown in the animated gif.

Comment: I'd use a library that supports this out of box instead. For example http://fabricjs.com. AFAIK, you have to do this manually in PIXI.